# What is the meaning of "All of this hits by 6:00, 6:30."?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "All of this hits by 6:00, 6:30." ?

> Det. Lipranzer: I'm supposed to be in the chief's office 8:00 tomorrow
>   to be interviewed By Molto. No discussion. Interview. It's like
>   they're after me, right? Another thing. When I came  back tonight they
>   took all the receipts of the evidence I inventoried on Polhemus. No
>   questions asked.
>
> Rozart: Sounds like you're off the case.
>
> Det. Lipranzer: Sure. Fine, but figure this in. I'm at the North
>   Branch before 5:00, going through the microfilm. **All of this hits by
>   6:00, 6:30.** Look what I picked up while I was out there. The case
>   number matches the complaint number  that was missing when you saw
>   Kenneally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***All of this hits by 6:00, 6:30*** refers to everything Lipranzer describes in the first paragraph. ***Hits*** is just slang for "happens," but is a little more dramatic.

So what Lipranzar is saying is that he got to the branch at 5:00, but he didn't get the receipts taken from him until 6 or 6:30. So he had that short period of 60 to 90 minutes to look at the microfilm, which is when he found the missing piece of evidence.